# Updating DataGridView cell immediately after edited

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

First of all, greetings to you guys.

I've been struggling trying to update a DGV immediately after edited.
I am using Access Database at the moment and trying to edit by using OleDbCommands.

This is my code, the issue is specifically within variable **numfolio**.

Once the function is done, new value on cell should be +1, and the next time i click the button, it should show me new value but it doesn't do it.

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance guys.

```
Private Sub btnCobrar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCobrar.Click

    Dim fecha As String = DateTime.Now
    Dim numfolio As Integer = VariablesDataGridView(1, 0).Value

    MsgBox(numfolio)
    numfolio += 1

    ' Enumeración de Folios
    con.Open()
    querystring = "Update Variables Set Valor ='" & numfolio & "' where Id=1"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(querystring, con)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: You have changed the dabase table, but this is not automatically propagated to the gridview. You need to update the gridview datasource or reload everything from the db

Comment: Solved it this way, i was completely missing this out.

Thanks Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Now is there scenario that whether the record is not updated in table at all? Or is it updating after every click?

So you need to put the code in

```
            Try
            Catch ex As System.Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
```

to trace the code execution.

To update after button click, your DGV you have to exclusively bind assigning DGV.DataSource

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

I managed to solve it by binding the Data Source as you mentioned @Steve mentioned.